# Getting directory's permissions via FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to get permissions of a directory via FTP command "STAT" like this:

```
$directory_list = ftp_raw($conn_id,'STAT '.$path);
```

The above command lists entire directory contents , including files and subdirs. I then search the returned data array for the directory i need to check, and retrieve something like:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 user  group     77824 May 13 10:15 Targetdir
```

This will let me parse the drwxr-xr-x string to find out that the chmod of the Targetdir is 0755.

Problem is, when the containing directory has 5000 files. A) It takes a very long time, and B)  the ftp_raw function just returns empty array 1 in 10 runs. I don't know if it's timing out or what exactely is the problem.

Is there are a better way to find directory's permissions ? Is there a way to limit number of retrieved fiels in "STAT" command ? I really need just the top 5 , no need for the other 4995 files.

Does anyone know, why would my command NOT run 100% of the time? Why would it break ? I cannot even reproduce my error, it happens randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example of [ftp_exec](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-exec.php) in manual. You can generate files list that way, then download it and parse.

```
ftp_exec($conn_id, 'ls -al >files.txt');
```

or if you know the name of directory and it is single one:

```
ftp_exec($conn_id, 'ls -ld '.$DIRECTORY.' >permissions.txt');
```

If you don't have exec permission try:

```
ftp_nlist ($conn, "-ld ".$DIRECTORY);
```

Comment: I would assume that EXEC is not widely supported or enabled, as I can imagine the security nightmare with that command.

Comment: as Krumelur mentioned, we have EXEC disabled on our machines . Any other way ?

Comment: Try ftp_nlist ($conn, "-ld ".$DIRECTORY);

Comment: I can use ftp_rawlist($conn, $DIRECTORY) which gives the list of files with permissions, owner and group information